# 'RM' is not recognized as an internal or external command while using laravel new blog

Tags: laravel, cmd, compiler-errors

When i typ on cmd laravel new blog. I get that error message. RM' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I could not find the solution on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```